# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence in NLP

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter

I am extracting keywords using python using YAKE and I am passing a csv file and extracting the keywords from column which are having sentences and length of the column is 748 and file is as follows:

[image]

I'm using Python YAKE to extract keywords from the Content column and the code is as given below:

[image]

so, if I change [:350] to any number, i am getting the error as:

[image]

Requesting for help?

Thank you.

Comment: change [:5] is right? The code looks right abs.

Comment: If i put [:5] then it will print only first 5 but I want to print all 748, if i change it to [:748], then i am getting the error as: 'Value Error: max() arg is an empty sequence'

Comment: Maybe some row contains invalid data (possible empty row)

Comment: Okay. In such case, can it print None. Can you help how to put it inside 'else if' statement.

Comment: I also think there's something wrong with the data, maybe special characters. Add ```print(post)``` in for loop and check which line is error

Comment: Thank you Johnny, I can see, there are so many special characters and I added the print statement. I have removed every special character and bring it to lower case. But, my problem is I need to print the keywords for all the entire column, where i am getting same error as above mentioned.